# F# Generics not so generic

Tags: generics, f#, c#-to-f#

I've come up against this a couple of times, but I'm really at a loss as to why it happens.

I've got a discriminated union like:

```
type MStep<'A, 'B> =
| Shuttle of Quotations.Expr<'B> * Quotations.Expr<'B>
```

There's more to the union, but this shows the basic problem.

If I do:

```
let s1 = Shuttle(<@ l.SomeIntProp @>, <@ r.SomeIntProp @>)
let s2 = Shuttle(<@ l.SomeStrProp @>, <@ r.SomeStrProp @>)
```

I get a compiler error:

> This expression was expected to have type int, but here has type string

Likewise, if I create them in the other order (string then int), I get the same error but the other way around.

I can see that the compiler is likely inferring `'B` based on my usage, but what if I want `'B` to be truly generic?

---

As requested here is a more complete example:

```
type MStep<'A, 'B> =
    | Shuttle of Quotations.Expr<'B> * Quotations.Expr<'B>
    | Ident of Quotations.Expr<'B>
    | Trans of Quotations.Expr<'A> * Quotations.Expr<'B> * ('A -> 'B)

let doMig (f:Table<'A>, t:Table<'B>, s:('A * 'B -> MStep<'C, 'D> list)) =
    ignore()

let a = doMig(bpdb.Adjustments, ndb.Adjustments, (fun (l,r) ->
    [
        Shuttle(<@ l.Id @>, <@ r.Id @>)
        Shuttle(<@ l.Name @>, <@ r.Name @>)
    ]
    ))
```

This produces the compiler error as seen above.

**NOTE:**

`bpdb` and `ndb` are both database contexts provided by the `SqlDataConnection` type provider.

The open namespaces are:

```
open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq
open System.Xml
open System.Xml.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns
open System.Reflection
open System.Diagnostics
```

Comment: I suspect there is some other code somewhere that is influencing this.  Try to produce a minimal example to show the problem (do we need `'A`?

Comment: Your example is still not complete. I can't paste your example in fsi and reproduce the error. Where is Table defined? Where is bpdb and ndb? Please include the namespaces you are opening as well.

Comment: I think it might even be an instance of the value restriction - if I simplify it to: `type M<'a,'b> = M of Quotations.Expr<'b>` it will produce those

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is obvious here:

```
let t = [ //inserted t to have a concrete variable
    Shuttle(<@ l.Id @>, <@ r.Id @>); 
    Shuttle(<@ l.Name @>, <@ r.Name @>)
]
```

What exactly is the type of `t`.  The first element gives `MStep<_,int> list` and the second gives `MStep<_,string>` which are different.

You can only put elements that are the same type into a list.

Comment: I knew only items of the same time could go into a list, completely overlooked it in this instance! Do you know of any way to get around this? Obviously I could use untyped quotations, but I kind of want the type checking for them...

Comment: @Clint - the problem is that any approach that allows you to combine different typed objects will by its nature lose type safety.

Comment: @Clint - there are two possibilities that I can think of: use generic subtypes of a non-generic base type and upcast your individual entries before putting them into the list (which may make consuming the list harder, but which should be relatively easy to implement on the producing side), or encode an existential type (which is much more complicated, but probably "morally" what you want - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992466/heterogeneous-lists-through-flexible-types/21996352#21996352).